# Querying multiple tables and then totalling

Tags: ms-access

So I have 4 queries:

- Jobs Query
- Timesheet Query
- Mileage Query
- Expenses Query

Timesheet, Mileage and Expenses Queries all have a field (job_ID) which relates to the ID field in tblJobs. I have created a report that pulls together information (as subreports) into a Main Report, which queries Jobs Query.

For each Job, I wanted an A4 report page which detailed any associated costs, from the remaining 3 tables, subtotals them and then totals them at the bottom of the page. This is to assist with invoice generation at the company I work at.

Everything works fine, but the report produces an A4 page for every job (all 2,300 or so), even where there is no related charges outstanding. How can I filter the report to only bring back jobs that have a total of £0.01 or more in total from the three tables (tblTimesheet, tblExpenses and tblMileage)?

I guessed it would be done via the query that the Main Report looks to. I think it can be achieved by creating an extra column in the query that sums any costs from tblTimesheet, tblExpenses and tblMileage for the job_ID and then filters only those results with a value of >£0.00

I can work out how to filter, but not how to create that extra column in the query that pulls the information and sums it.

Any pointers?

**SQL code for the queries below:**

*Jobs Query:*

```
SELECT tblJobs.ID, [tblClients]![client_name] AS Client, "R" & [ref] AS [Job No], tblJobs.title AS [Job Title]
FROM tblClients INNER JOIN tblJobs ON tblClients.[ID] = tblJobs.[client_ID];
```

*Timesheet Query:*

```
SELECT tblTimesheet.job_ID, tblTimesheet.datetime AS [Date], [firstName] & " " & [surname] AS Consultant, tblTimesheet.Activity, tblTimesheet.Hours, tblTimesheet.Rate, CCur([hours]*[rate]) AS Cost
FROM tblConsultants INNER JOIN tblTimesheet ON tblConsultants.[ID] = tblTimesheet.[consultant_ID];
```

*Expenses Query:*

```
SELECT tblExpenses.job_ID, tblExpenses.datetime AS [Date], [firstName] & " " & [surname] AS Consutlant, tblExpenses.Description, tblExpenses.cost
FROM (tblConsultants INNER JOIN tblJobs ON tblConsultants.[ID] = tblJobs.[main_SGP_consultant]) INNER JOIN tblExpenses ON tblConsultants.[ID] = tblExpenses.[consultant_ID];
```

*Mileage Query:*

```
SELECT tblMileage.job_ID, tblMileage.datetime, [firstName] & " " & [surname] AS Consultant, tblMileage.Description, tblMileage.Miles, CCur([miles]*0.5) AS Cost
FROM tblConsultants INNER JOIN tblMileage ON tblConsultants.[ID] = tblMileage.[consultant_ID];
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL you're using for the query at the moment?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have updated the post so it is more clear. Hope this helps.